# Item to right Side?

Tags: android

I am trying to keep all item to right side I find code in Google but it is not working with me.

[image]

**latest_lsv_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.apps.newsapplication"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.example.util.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_newslistlatest"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="13dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:border_color="@color/divider"
        app:border_width="8dip"

        app:round_background="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_newslistheadinglatest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_lastest.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lsv_latest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

if you want more code or file I will past it here...
activity_main.xml
LastFragment.java
etc...

I try to use RTL but also not working with me

Comment: you need to use custom ListView, check this link; http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Have you tried forcing RTL layout? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-international-users

Comment: Did you try using RelativeLayout in your ListItem?